# Adding default widget in android launcher

Tags: android, android-widget, android-launcher

I am trying  launcher3 OSP from git . i have added an widget  in default_workspace.xml file but widgets are not shown in home screen by default . Are there any other thing should i do for that ?

default_workspace.xml

```
<favorites xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/com.android.launcher3">



<appwidget
    launcher:className="com.sec.android.widgetapp.digitalclock.DigitalClockWidgetProvider"
    launcher:packageName="com.sec.android.widgetapp.digitalclock"
    launcher:screen="2"
    launcher:spanX="2"
    launcher:spanY="2"
    launcher:x="1"
    launcher:y="0" />

<!-- Hotseat -->
<include launcher:workspace="@xml/dw_tablet_hotseat" />

<!-- Bottom row -->
<favorite
    launcher:screen="0"
    launcher:x="0"
    launcher:y="-1"
    launcher:uri="#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.APP_CONTACTS;end" />

<resolve
    launcher:screen="0"
    launcher:x="-1"
    launcher:y="-1" >
    <favorite launcher:uri="#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.APP_MARKET;end" />
    <favorite launcher:uri="market://details?id=com.android.launcher" />
</resolve>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code but from Android 8.0 (Oreo) we actually need to ask for permission in other to be able to display home screen widget and one task to test this is to try to add any widget to your custom launcher: you will see that it will ask you for some permission in other to be added.

Now, one thing you can try considering is if you are adding the home screen widget via default_workspace.xml it actually won't be able to ask for this permission.

To resolve this issue, first of all:

Go to the class LauncherProvider.java: you can find it in this link:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/launcher3/LauncherProvider.java

You can scan through it for this method:

```
 private boolean initializeExternalAdd(ContentValues values) {
    // 1. Ensure that externally added items have a valid item id
    int id = mOpenHelper.generateNewItemId();
    values.put(LauncherSettings.Favorites._ID, id);
    // 2. In the case of an app widget, and if no app widget id is specified, we
    // attempt allocate and bind the widget.
    Integer itemType = values.getAsInteger(LauncherSettings.Favorites.ITEM_TYPE);
    if (itemType != null &&
            itemType.intValue() == LauncherSettings.Favorites.ITEM_TYPE_APPWIDGET &&
            !values.containsKey(LauncherSettings.Favorites.APPWIDGET_ID)) {
        final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getContext());
        ComponentName cn = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(
                values.getAsString(Favorites.APPWIDGET_PROVIDER));
        if (cn != null) {
            try {
                AppWidgetHost widgetHost = mOpenHelper.newLauncherWidgetHost();
                int appWidgetId = widgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();
                values.put(LauncherSettings.Favorites.APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
                if (!appWidgetManager.bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed(appWidgetId,cn)) {
                    widgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(appWidgetId);
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to initialize external widget", e);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now you can replace that with this:

```
 private boolean initializeExternalAdd(ContentValues values) {
    // 1. Ensure that externally added items have a valid item id
    int id = mOpenHelper.generateNewItemId();
    values.put(LauncherSettings.Favorites._ID, id);

    // 2. In the case of an app widget, and if no app widget id is specified, we
    // attempt allocate and bind the widget.
    Integer itemType = values.getAsInteger(LauncherSettings.Favorites.ITEM_TYPE);
    if (itemType != null &&
            itemType.intValue() == LauncherSettings.Favorites.ITEM_TYPE_APPWIDGET &&
            !values.containsKey(LauncherSettings.Favorites.APPWIDGET_ID)) {

        final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getContext());
        ComponentName cn = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(
                values.getAsString(Favorites.APPWIDGET_PROVIDER));

        if (cn != null) {
            try {
                AppWidgetHost widgetHost = mOpenHelper.newLauncherWidgetHost();
                int appWidgetId = widgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();
                values.put(LauncherSettings.Favorites.APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

                /*Since we want to load the app widget immediately our app is loaded, we don't need to check for permissions. 
                checking if the permission is accepted is not necessary and that is why we commented
                this line of code
                */
                /*if (!appWidgetManager.bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed(appWidgetId,cn)) {
                    widgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(appWidgetId);
                    return false;
                }*/
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to initialize external widget", e);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now, LauncherProvider won't be able to delete our AppWidgetId and the permission is automatically accepted.